# Improving a mysql simple text search for a one-word column

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a one-word column with about 10000 rows. Searching for a certain word is ok but should be faster - right now I'm using

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word='hello'
```

This query takes 0.0004 secs to be exec.

I've created a FULLTEXT on the word column, but the time for the query to exec is exactly the same.
What would you do?

Comment: You just want exact matching, right? It _sounds_ like the column should be indexed, not a fulltexted.

Comment: Please post the time required to execute the query and the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM words WHERE word='hello'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no gain in a FULLTEXT index if it's only one world. That is used to index parts of larger texts so that they can be searched.

I assume you already have a normal index on word. You could experiment with setting the [length of the index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html) but it might not improve.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM words WHERE MATCH (word) AGAINST ('hello')`

For more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html